# No enruta bien las paginas de VUE

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

tengo una web con VUE que parece que falla al intentar enrutar las paginas, en local funcional si  la pongo en localhost:8080/ pero al subirla al servidor, el .htacces hace la llamada al index.html y desde alli no entra a la aplicación.

En local si hago la llamada con localhost:8080/index.html también ocurre el mismo problema.

**Index.html**

```
 <html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

El App.vue carga la cabecera (Cap.vue) y esta si que aparece pero cuando tiene que ir al **router-view** y cargar la primera pagina (la raiz /), no lo hace.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app>
      <Cap />
      <v-main>
        <router-view/>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Cap from '@/components/Cap.vue'
  export default {
        name: 'app',

        components: {
          Cap,
        }
    };
</script>
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import auth from "@/logic/auth";


Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'Login',
        component: () =>
            import ( /* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/Login.vue'),
        //meta: { requiresAuth: false }
    },

    {
        path: '/historico/:shop?',
        name: 'historico',
        component: () =>
            import ( /* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/Camp.vue'),
        meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    },
    

]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
        if (!auth.getUserLogged()) {
            // Sino esta validado, vuelve a la raiz
            next({
                name: "Login"
            });
        } else {
            next()
        }
    } else {
        next()
    }
});


export default router;
```

Comment: ¿Te aseguraste de correr la versión que surge de `npm run build` en el servidor?

Comment: si, de momento he hecho una solución que no me parece muy limpia pero que funciona. Poner otro PATH identico al de '/' pero con 'index.html'